# Zsh bindkey map Ctrl+c To Ctrl+p

Tags: linux, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I know how to map CTRL+L to run a command like 'ls'

```bash
bindkey -s "^L" 'ls^M'
```

but how can I map CTRL+c to another key stroke like CTRL+p in my ZSH?

Or what is the command to kill the current running process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^C` is the *interrupt* character for the system's terminal driver by default, what you press to abort things like commands or long running completions, etc. The shell is not involved in that.

You'd need to bind that to something else for zsh's binding in its own line editor to be effective. Otherwise, `zle` never sees a `^C` character coming when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, as it is intercepted by the system to generate a SIGINT signal instead.

```
stty intr '^G'
bindkey -s '^C' whatever
```

Or:

```
bindkey '^C' up-line-or-history
```

To bind the same widget as bound to `^P` by default in `emacs` mode.

For `^G` to be the `intr` character only while `zle` is running, you can do:

```
autoload add-zle-hook-widget
intr-is-cC() stty intr '^C' < /dev/tty
intr-is-cG() stty intr '^G' < /dev/tty
zle -N intr-is-cC
zle -N intr-is-cG
add-zle-hook-widget line-init intr-is-cG
add-zle-hook-widget line-finish intr-is-cC

bindkey -s '^C' whatever
```

Where `intr` is set to `^G` and `^C` when zle starts (after the prompt is issued) and ends (when you leave the prompt) respectively.